# How does a Java thread which has been put to sleep() throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, sleep

My question considers, as an example, the scenario where the thread T is put to sleep for X time, and then T gets an interrupt call from another thread, which will make it raise an InterruptedException at some point. I'm mainly concerned with the performance impact of the implementation choice for this, and why is it low or high. From my understating of how things work on a low level, a java sleep() call calls inside of it the sleep function of the OS, which instructs the scheduler to keep the thread in a non executing state and check every Y time for each thread if the sleep time has elapsed (this check is triggered by a signal separate from the cpu clock that is thrown once every many clock cycles, as to not have too much impact on performance).

1. Is this correct?
2. I'm guessing that one solution might be that the sleep(x) method in java has an internal cycle that repeatedly checks for the interrupted flag. If this didn't call the sleep function of the OS, the thread would keep getting scheduled just repeating that check and consuming a lot of cpu time(as much as a thread that is not sleeping and working without interruptions). Does the java sleep(x) method actually call the OS sleep(t) more than once, with t being a fraction of x, so that the thread performs the check on the interrupted flag once in a while? This would still mean that every thread that is sleeping gets woken and put to sleep again multiple times, is this optimal?
3. If question 2 is false, what does actually happen?

Edit: I'm assuming a scenario where the OS has threads implemented and the JVM uses them, if this changes the possible answer to this question.

Comment: I reckon the question can be only answered with: It depends. If the OS/Platform does not support threads, the JRE would use green threads (i.e. a SW implementation), if the JRE nicely integrates with the OS, the platform's scheduling will be used. Anything in between may be possible. So it depends, on Platform, OS, JRE implementation.

Comment: @king_nak Java hasn't had green threads since 1997 (and the virtual threads going into preview in Java 19 are not green threads as were used in the early Java versions).

Comment: My point might have been lost in the kind of long digression I made(it was just to check if I got some base knowledge wrong that made me ask the question in the first place). What I am asking is basically how can a thread that I invoked sleep(x) on  throw exceptions before x time has passed, since the first explanation that comes to my mind is that the thread has to execute to throw exceptions(which it shouldn't if "sleeping") . If this is very "environment dependent" any example would be a great answer, maybe one regarding the most likely software+hardware configurations currently available

Comment: A typical implementation of interruption will use signals while typically running on an operating system where a signal can stop an ongoing `sleep` call.